# What is curl used for in Ruby?

Tags: installation, ruby, rvm, curl

I am a fairly new used and was looking for a way to install Ruby on my laptop and came across this link:
https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

When I use the command specified there, it says curl is not installed. So can anyone tell me what exactly curl is?  Thanks!

> **Note:** Reading [this guide](http://www.rubypluspl.us/2012/06/ubuntu-1204-ruby-on-rails-development.html) is highly recommended before you install Ruby (thanks Damien).

Comment: The question has been answered but id suggest looking at this guide instead before installing ruby http://www.rubypluspl.us/2012/06/ubuntu-1204-ruby-on-rails-development.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CURL is needed for rvm, specifically it is used for the installer script (which is made to be 'run everywhere'), and since Mac doesn't ship with wget but does with curl, they use curl.

From [CURL man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/curl.1.html)

> curl  is  a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of
>   the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS,
>   IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP,LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP,
>   SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP).  The command is designed to work without user
>   interaction.

You can install it by `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: @ Programming Noob- You should definitely  consider the [link](http://www.rubypluspl.us/2012/06/ubuntu-1204-ruby-on-rails-development.html) provided by **damien** above.

Comment: Installing Ruby from the package manager is a recipe for disaster if you start getting serious with Ruby. As for why it is actually needed for rvm, it is used for the installer script (which is made to be 'run everywhere', and since Mac doesn't ship with wget but does with curl... you get the picture).